# Deleting from select list and database - HTML5

Tags: jquery, html

I have a function which is meant to remove an item from a select list onclick of a button and also remove that option from my database. The code is below:

```
function removeOption(id, column){
    var checkdel = $('#'+id+' option:selected').text();
    $('#'+id+'option:selected').remove();//not working
    $('#'+id+'').selectmenu('refresh', true);//not working

    if (!window.openDatabase) {
        alert('Databases are not supported in this browser.');
        return;
    }

    db.transaction(function(transaction) {
        transaction.executeSql('DELETE FROM TABLE1 WHERE "'+ column +'" = "'+checkdel+'"\
        ',
        nullHandler);
    });

    return;
}
```

The remove from database is working correctly and I have verified that, but the jquery isn't working to delete them from the select list visually. Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the space before option selector.try this:

```
$('#'+id+' option:selected').remove();
$('#'+id).selectmenu('refresh', true);
```

Comment: Worked perfectly!  I get confused by the quotation marks sometimes and miss out spaces etc, thanks for helping :)

Comment: @Mohd : practice using variables as selector. will help you reduce the confusion.